# Enable Xposed modules from shell

Tags: android, adb, xposed-framework

Is there an API to enable an `Xposed` module in Android from the shell (using `ADB`) and not through the device's UI.

This is constantly a bother for automation, when we need to install our module on a clean test emulator. This is currently the only step that we are required to do manually.

A simple google search + overview of the `XPosed` documentation didn't yield anything worth while.

Answer (score 6):

As you already know, this is approach disfavored for end-users, but for testing, you have to echo the path of the apk to Xposed config file:

Pre-Lollipop:

```
adb shell "echo '/data/app/com.xyz.example-1.apk' >> /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/modules.list"
```

Lollipop and newer:

```
adb shell "echo '/data/app/com.xyz.example-1 OR -2/base.apk' >> /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/modules.list"
```

For these commands you need to have your emulator support root adb, type

```
adb root
```

into the command line. If your emulator doesn't support rooted/insecure adbd, you can also add a *su -c* before the *echo* to get root rights.

EDIT: the easiest way to find which number you have to use in directory name would be what @brendan suggested.

Comment: doesn't work for me. The module is still not enabled after adding it to the modules.list file

Comment: Did you reboot then and check the file after that again? Also be sure it was actually written to the file. Maybe you even need to reboot twice?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on KitKat:

(1)  Update shared_pres xml file:

If you look at the `/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/shared_prefs/` directory.  You will see an `enabled_modules.xml` file.

In my case I was only working with a single module so I would just overwrite the file.  If you have several modules you may wish to do an edit/update.

I would have a local `enabled_modules.xml` file that looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<map>
  <int name="com.companyname.xposedmodule" value="1" />
</map>
```

...where `com.companyname.xposedmodule` is the name of your module.

Then post build you can execute a simple:

`adb push enabled_modules.xml /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/shared_prefs/`

(2)  Update modules.list config file:

You also need to do what @Maxr1998 suggested.  I scripted it this way:

```
adb shell "[ -f /data/app/com.companyname.xposedmodule-1.apk ] && echo '/data/app/com.companyname.xposedmodule-1.apk' >> /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/modules.list
adb shell "[ -f /data/app/com.companyname.xposedmodule-2.apk ] && echo '/data/app/com.companyname.xposedmodule-2.apk' >> /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/modules.list
```